# Center element with percent size against page size

Tags: html, css, height, width

I need to center a div vertically and horizontally, and have its size be a certain percentage of the whole page (say 80%).

**I can do this with vh and vw units** ([link](http://jsfiddle.net/PiranhaGreg/C9fpp/))

```
<style>
html, body
{
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0;
}

body > div
{
    position: absolute;
    background-color: red;
    top: 10vh;
    left: 10vw;
    width: 80vw;
    height: 80vh;
}
</style>
<div></div>
```

**...or with old table design** ([link](http://jsfiddle.net/PiranhaGreg/Kyru9/))

```
<style>
html, body
{
    margin: 0;
    height: 100%;
}

#center
{
    background-color: red;
}
</style>
<table height="100%" width="100%">
    <tr height="10%"></tr>
    <tr>
        <td width="10%"></td>
        <td id="center"></td>
        <td width="10%"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr height="10%"></tr>
</table>
```

But I would like to support a div version. Can anyone provide any help?

Comment: Just putting it out there that `vh` and `vw` are pretty well supported. http://caniuse.com/#feat=viewport-units

Comment: I need support for Android Browser too :-(

Comment: Vertical centering is not something CSS is well-equipped to do. If you don't like your current solutions, then JavaScript is probably your best option.

Comment: Somewhere in your design, you will need a **VALUE** to base your relative size calculations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A common way of displaying a divider in the middle of a page is to display it as a table with a table cell:

```html
<body>
    <div id="wrapper">
        <div id="inner">
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

```css
html, body { margin:0; height:100%; }
body { display:table; width:100%; }
#wrapper { display:table-cell; vertical-align:middle; height:100%; width:100%; }
#inner { height:50%; width:50%; margin:0 auto; }
```

[**JSFiddle example**](http://jsfiddle.net/JamesD/Rhyxu/).

In this example, `#inner` is 50% width and height of `#wrapper` which is 100% width and height of the page body.

As `#wrapper` is displayed as a `table-cell` within a body displayed as `table`, the content within will be affected by the `vertical-align:middle` property, causing the `#inner` divider to be in the vertical middle of the page.

Applying `margin:0 auto;` to the `#inner` divider then aligns it to the horizontal middle.

---

The beauty of this is that you don't need to worry about offsetting the `#inner` divider, and aren't limited to just using percentage widths. Fixed widths will still be aligned in the middle of the containing `#wrapper`.

This is supported on all modern browsers: http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-table